# Load (custom) module via JSPM

Tags: javascript, jspm

I have a module: `Cow.js` inside `/src/lib/`. Then in my unit test (`/test/spec/Cow-test.js`), I want to be able to reference it via `import { Cow } from 'Cow';` as I do with all dependencies/libraries imported by JSPM.

The issue is that I have to do it like `import { Cow } from '../../src/lib/Cow';`, by specifying the path.

Is there any way I can do it the way I'm asking, without having to worry where I am and where the module is located?

The reasoning behind this is: I can move/refactor modules to any location and the path should be in one place (e.g.: in the JSPM config file), not everywhere I'm referencing them.

Any clues?

**PS:** I can share any source code: the classes/modules.

This is part of my JSPM config file:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '',
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: 'babel',
  babelOptions: {
    'optional': ['runtime', 'optimisation.modules.system']
  },
  paths: {
    '*': '*.js',
    'github:*': 'jspm_packages/github/*',
    'npm:*': 'jspm_packages/npm/*'
  },
  map: {
    'babel': 'npm:babel-core@5.8.34',
    'babel-runtime': 'npm:babel-runtime@5.8.34',
    'chai': 'npm:chai@3.4.1',
...
```

...and this is my (very tiny) project structure:

```
|   .babelrc
|   config.js
|   gulpfile.babel.js
|   karma.conf.js
|   package.json
|
+---jspm_packages/
|
+---node_modules/
|
+---src
|   |   bootstrap.js
|   |   main.js
|   |
|   \---lib
|           Cow.js
|
\---test
    |
    \---spec
            Cow-test.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a package declaration inside the config file of JSPM.

For example you could declare a package `Cow`, and then import it using: `import Cow from 'Cow';`.

See the documentation here:
- https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm
- https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages

---

You could also define a path to a folder inside the config file of JSPM.
Say you have folder `lib/`, and have some files (cow.js, sheep.js ...), you could import that way: `import cow from 'lib/cow.js'`.

Inside config.json:

```
{
    ...
    "path": {
        "lib/": "src/lib/"
    },
    ...
}
```

See documentation here: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#paths